# MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT and Hibernate Auto ID generation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Is it necessary to have DB Column defined as `AUTO_INCREMENT` to have Entity `@Id` Auto generation working properly? I am using Spring-Data-JPA with MySQL.

Comment: It is not mandatory to define column in DB with AUTO_INCREMENT, for @Id field in Hibernate entity class. Please mark as answered if it answers your query

Comment: Correct. I'm trying to understand if @GeneratedValue [by default AUTO Generation Strategy] should take precedence over AUTO_INCREMENT or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to define column in DB with AUTO_INCREMENT, for @Id field in Hibernate entity class.